# Column value occurs more than X times

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to only select rows where the `trends.insights_taxonomy` column value occurs over X times. I've been avoiding COUNT() as I do not what to do any grouping, I want all the correlating rows to remain unique.

I'm trying to weed out outliers, so for example, if I had a database of 100k peoples favorite colors, I want to ignore colors that occur less than 50 times.

Is this where a subquery would come in?

```
SELECT insights.industry,insights.city,insights.country,metrics.engagements,metrics.number_of_people_at_company, trends.insights_taxonomy,
FROM production.scores.api_company,
UNNEST(insights) AS insights,
UNNEST(metrics) AS metrics,
UNNEST(trends) AS trends
WHERE insights.industry <> ""
AND insights.city <> ""
AND insights.country <> ""
AND metrics.number_of_people_at_company > 0
AND metrics.engagements > 10
```

Not sure the best way to format this, but the top row is the column labels and the second row are the values. In this case I only want rows where Cisco Systems occurs more than X times.

```
industry | city | country | engagements | people_at_company | taxonomy
Legal Counsel and Prosecution | Madison | United States | 11 | 5 | Cisco Systems
```

Comment: simplified sample data and expected output would help a lot

Comment: this example does not really match the original question. I recommend you to simplify your case to present only core of the problem you have so it might be easier then for you to explain it (problem) and present sample data as well as expected result. see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using a sub query, hopefully this is helpful for someone else.

```
SELECT insights.industry,insights.city,insights.country,metrics.engagements,metrics.number_of_people_at_company, trends.insights_taxonomy, trends.total_interactions
FROM production.scores.api_company,
UNNEST(insights) AS insights,
UNNEST(metrics) AS metrics,
UNNEST(trends) AS trends
WHERE trends.insights_taxonomy IN 
  (SELECT trends.insights_taxonomy
  FROM production.scores.api_company,
  UNNEST(trends) AS trends
  GROUP BY insights_taxonomy
  HAVING count(*) > 100)
AND insights.city <> ""
AND insights.country <> ""
AND metrics.number_of_people_at_company > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to group your resulting data, then you need to determine your qualifying rows *before* you get your resulting data. Write a grouping query to determine the qualifying rows, and then you can either JOIN the data set against your query above to gather everything without groupings, or perform a WHERE x IN (your grouping subquery returning valid things you want to see the complete data for).